# Ordenar produtos por popularidad en woocommerce(más vistos)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo una web en wordpress con woocommerce, no la utilizo para ventas, solamente como catálogo.
Necesito ordenar los productos de acuerdo a la popularidad (o más vistos).
La popularidad que trae wordpress es según la cantidad de ventas, yo necesito que sea según la cantidad de visitas que tiene el producto.
Como se podría hacer?

Alguna funcion en functions.php o modificar single-product.php?

Actualmente he encontrado estas funciones pero no ordenan por más vistos.

```
    <?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? woocommerce_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Tenias que haber traducido la otra , no crear una nueva ....v.v

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, lo podrías hacer con una query muy simple, debido a que woocommerce guarda los productos como si fueran Posts...

Te la dejo aquí abajo:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'post_views', 'order' => 'DESC'));
```

Puedes añadir-lo en la query donde recuperas los productos, te debería funcionar, sino guardas las visitas en los productos prueba en seguir este tutorial (algo más complejo pero muy claro)

http://subharanjan.com/how-to-display-wordpress-posts-sorted-by-post-view-count-solved-without-a-plugin/

[wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) [woocommerce](/questions/tagged/woocommerce)